# C++ converting templates with operator overload

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class where I try to convert a template verision to another via operator overload

```
enum MyTypes {A,B,C}

template<MyTypes T>
MyClass {
    const static MyType type_ = T;
    template<MyTypes U>       
    MyClass<U> convert(MyTypes t) {
        MyType<U> ret = MyType<U>();
        ....
        return r;
    }
    template<MyTypes U>      
    MyClass<U> operator()() {
        return convert(U);
    }
}
```

However, this yields (on gcc, c11)

```
conversion from MyClass<0u> to non-scalar type MyClass<1u> requested
```

removing the template functions and trying

```
MyClass<A> operator()() {
    MyClass<A> a = MyClass<A>();
    ...
    return a;
}
```

throws

```
the error operator cannot be overloaded
```

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is that if I have

```
MyClass<A> a = MyClass<A>;
MyClass<B> b = a;
```

that it creates a new MyClass based on a and the conversion. Any idea what my mistake here is?

EDIT:
I tossed out one template function, just leaving the operator

```
template<MyTypes U>      
MyClass<U> operator()() {
    MyClass<U> ret = MyClass<U>();
    ...
    return ret;
}
```

but this still yields

```
conversion from MyClass<0u> to non-scalar type MyClass<1u> requested
```

when trying to do

```
MyClass<B> = a
```

Comment: `convert(U)`. What is the template parameter here? No. It's not `U`. Think about it.

Comment: What is `MyType`? What is `r`? Can you post a [mcve] that we can copy and paste and get the exact same error message?

Comment: Sorry but... with `MyType<U> ret = MyType<U>();` (inside `convert()`), do you mean `MyClass<U> r = MyClass<U>();` ?

Comment: @max66... I think you are right, I stuffed up something in that function. I tossed it out to avoid that extra hassle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following converts the value and allows for the assignment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum MyTypes { A, B, C };

template<MyTypes T>
struct MyClass{
    const static MyTypes type_ = T;
    std::string history{"started as " + std::to_string(T)};

    template<MyTypes U>
    operator MyClass<U> () {
        return {history+" then became " + std::to_string(U)};
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<A> a;
    MyClass<B> b = a;
    MyClass<C> c = b;

    std::cout << a.history << '\n';
    std::cout << b.history << '\n';
    std::cout << c.history << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
started as 0
started as 0 then became 1
started as 0 then became 1 then became 2
```

Comment: Thanks, taht fixed it. Looks like my base mistake among other little items was accidentally overloading the wrong operator